# Editing Daniel2 Cinegy out of pendrive USB3, possible?

Tags: premiere, editing, pro, usb

Does a USB3.0 pen/thumb drive have enough speed to handle editing in Premiere Pro Daniel2 codecs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the USB flash drive, for example some have > 100 MB/s R/W capability and would be similar to working with a traditional HDD. However USB flash drives have chips which are not meant for constant use and lots of writing, and they don't have wear leveling like a good SSD. This means that the flash drive will go bad sooner and you will lose your data when it does.

I recommend using a portable SSD to work with your video projects. For example a Samsung T5 series.

Comment: Thank you, you have right. External drive will be better